# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to copy a matrix

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am making a program which is checking words against a dictionary, the program checks each letter in a word against a word in a dictionary.
I want to optimize it by saving each difference in a matrix and then copy it for the next word if the word have some characters which are the same so the program doesn't have to recalculate everything. However with my current solution I get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, and I don't see the problem.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ClosestWords {
    LinkedList<String> closestWords = null;

    static int [][] SaveVal;
    int closestDistance = -1;
    static String savedWord;
    static String savedWrongWord;

    int partDist(String w1, String w2, int w1len, int w2len, int [][] SaveVal) {

        if (w1len == 0) {
            //return w2len;
            //SaveVal[0][w2len] = w2len;
            return w2len;
        }
        else if (w2len == 0) {
            //return w1len;
            //SaveVal[w1len][0] = w1len;
            return w1len;
        }
        else if(SaveVal[w1len-1][w2len-1] != 0) {
            return SaveVal[w1len-1][w2len-1];
        }

        int res = partDist(w1, w2, w1len - 1, w2len - 1, SaveVal) +
                (w1.charAt(w1len - 1) == w2.charAt(w2len - 1) ? 0 : 1);
        int addLetter = partDist(w1, w2, w1len - 1, w2len, SaveVal) + 1;
        if (addLetter < res)
            res = addLetter;
        int deleteLetter = partDist(w1, w2, w1len, w2len - 1, SaveVal) + 1;
        if (deleteLetter < res)
            res = deleteLetter;
        SaveVal[w1len-1][w2len-1] = res;
        return res;
    }

    int Distance(String w1, String w2) {
        int simLetters = checkSim(w1, w2);
        //System.out.println(simLetters);
        if(simLetters > 0)  {
            //Reuse the old array used before
            int [][] tempVal = new int [w1.length()][w2.length()]; // w2.length()
            for(int i = 0; i < SaveVal.length; i++)  {

                for(int j=0; j < SaveVal[i].length; j++)  {
    ############### ERRROR HERE WHEN RUNNING PROGRAM ############
                    tempVal[i][j] = SaveVal[i][j];
                }
            }



            SaveVal = tempVal;
            return (partDist(w1, w2, w1.length(), w2.length(), SaveVal));
        } else {
            //Completly new word
            SaveVal = new int [w1.length()][w2.length()];
            return (partDist(w1, w2, w1.length(), w2.length(), SaveVal));
        }
    }
        /*SaveVal = new int [w1.length()][w2.length()];
        return (partDist(w1, w2, w1.length(), w2.length(), SaveVal));*/

    int checkSim(String w1, String w2)  {
        int counter = 0;
        if(savedWord == null || !savedWrongWord.equals(w1))  {
            return 0;
        }
        char[] char1 = savedWord.toCharArray();
        char[] char2 = w2.toCharArray();
        if(char1.length > char2.length) {
            for(int x = 0; x < char2.length; x++)  {
                if(char1[x] == char2[x])  {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }else {
            for(int x = 0; x < char1.length; x++)  {
                if(char1[x] == char2[x])  {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public ClosestWords(String w, List<String> wordList) {
        savedWrongWord = w;
        for (String s : wordList) {
            int dist = Distance(w, s);
            savedWord = s;
            if (dist < closestDistance || closestDistance == -1) {
                closestDistance = dist;
                closestWords = new LinkedList<String>();
                closestWords.add(s);
            }
            else if (dist == closestDistance)
                closestWords.add(s);
        }
    }

    int getMinDistance() {
        return closestDistance;
    }

    List<String> getClosestWords() {
        return closestWords;
    }
}
```

Comment: which line do you get the exception at?

Comment: tempVal[i][j] = SaveVal[i][j];
It's around line 50

Comment: You pass around lots of vars and use different vars to create SaveVal and TempVal.  It's very hard to see exactly where the problem is, but SaveVal and TempVal should be the same size as each other and the same size as w1.length() and w2.length(), wherever they come from.

Comment: did i miss that there's a java feature where you don't need return types for your methods?

Comment: Could you give some test cases?

Answer (score 0):

You got exception because the SaveVal and tmpVal do not use the same w2.
In my test case:

```
        String w = "sa";
        List<String> arrays = new LinkedList<>();
        arrays.add("sdasfq");
        arrays.add("sad");
        ClosestWords words = new ClosestWords(w, arrays);
        System.out.println(words.getClosestWords());
```

The SaveVal was created by using the w1="sa" and w2="sdasfg". But, when w2 = "sad", the SaveVal wasn't created again. So the SaveVal is int[2][7] but the tmpVal is int[2][3].

You just use the SaveVal to accelerate method partDist execution. You should created the SaveVal every time when you iterate the wordList. I don't think that you can reuse the intermediate result between different w2, like "sdasfg", "sad".

So, you can just delete field SaveVal, and declare it as a local variable in method Distance()

```
    int Distance(String w1, String w2) {
        int SaveVal[][] = new int[w1.length()][w2.length()];
        return (partDist(w1, w2, w1.length(), w2.length(), SaveVal));
}
```

I can't understand method checkSim(). I think it's redundant.
The code is:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ClosestWords {
    LinkedList<String> closestWords = null;

//    int [][] SaveVal;
    int closestDistance = -1;
    static String savedWord;
    static String savedWrongWord;

    int partDist(String w1, String w2, int w1len, int w2len, int [][] SaveVal) {

        if (w1len == 0) {
            //return w2len;
            //SaveVal[0][w2len] = w2len;
            return w2len;
        }
        else if (w2len == 0) {
            //return w1len;
            //SaveVal[w1len][0] = w1len;
            return w1len;
        }
        else if(SaveVal[w1len-1][w2len-1] != 0) {
            return SaveVal[w1len-1][w2len-1];
        }

        int res = partDist(w1, w2, w1len - 1, w2len - 1, SaveVal) +
                (w1.charAt(w1len - 1) == w2.charAt(w2len - 1) ? 0 : 1);
        int addLetter = partDist(w1, w2, w1len - 1, w2len, SaveVal) + 1;
        if (addLetter < res)
            res = addLetter;
        int deleteLetter = partDist(w1, w2, w1len, w2len - 1, SaveVal) + 1;
        if (deleteLetter < res)
            res = deleteLetter;
        SaveVal[w1len-1][w2len-1] = res;
        return res;
    }

    int Distance(String w1, String w2) {
        int SaveVal[][] = new int[w1.length()][w2.length()];
        return (partDist(w1, w2, w1.length(), w2.length(), SaveVal));
    }


    public ClosestWords(String w, List<String> wordList) {
        savedWrongWord = w;
        for (String s : wordList) {
            int dist = Distance(w, s);
            savedWord = s;
            if (dist < closestDistance || closestDistance == -1) {
                closestDistance = dist;
                closestWords = new LinkedList<String>();
                closestWords.add(s);
            }
            else if (dist == closestDistance)
                closestWords.add(s);
        }
    }

    int getMinDistance() {
        return closestDistance;
    }

    List<String> getClosestWords() {
        return closestWords;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String w = "sa";
        List<String> arrays = new LinkedList<>();
        arrays.add("sdasfq");
        arrays.add("sad");
        ClosestWords words = new ClosestWords(w, arrays);
        System.out.println(words.getClosestWords());
    }

}
```